# Does connecting a PS5 controller to a PC via Bluetooth work and if so does it require additional software or drivers to function?

Tags: pc, controllers, ps5

I have bought a Dual Sense Playstation 5 controller, and a USB 5.0 bluetooth dongle.

I've tested the dongle by pairing it to my phone and my bluetooth speakers, and it works well.

The controller is fully charged, as I plugged it in and the light turned orange, and I left it for an hour until it was done (I assume it was already mostly charged as it was brand new).

I've tried pairing my PC to my controller, and it pairs fine. When I turn the controller on, windows reports it as 'Connected'.

However, about 10 seconds later the controller turns off. During the time it's switched on, Steam Big Picture cannot see the controller.

If I connect the controller via USB-C cable, then it's detected and functions perfectly.

Google suggests that it's possible to pair a PS5 controller to a PC via Bluetooth and have it function. However I've seen some posts that talk about DS4Windows or some kind of drivers being required to emulate functionality etc.

I've not been able to find any definitive posts by people saying yes, I have a PS5 controller and a PC and they function perfectly over Bluetooth.

So my question is, is it possible to connect the PS5 controller to a PC via Bluetooth, and if so does it require some kind of drivers or similar to function?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes this does require software at the moment**, I have used DualsenseX by the creators of Ds4Windows. DualsenseX is directly tailored towards a ps5 controller. It allows for the emulation of a ps4 controller and Xbox controller.
 I can confirm that this program works when the controller is plugged in. Not sure about Bluetooth but probably works aswell

Comment: According to DualsenseX's [github](https://github.com/Paliverse/DualSenseX), bluetooth is indeed supported. They also make a note that they have no website, so if NibblyPig plans on using this software, please grab it directly from the creator's github.